# Any idea how I could structure my project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've been teaching python courses for a while and I've started doing my own project to practice with the knowledge I learned. The problem is when it comes to structuring that I'm a little lost since I've always programmed on the web.

My project is about a virtual assistant, the one who listens and from that command makes an action.

I have it structured in this way:

```
main.py
vs
    • mediator.py
    • commands.py
    • skills.py
```

in skills.py I have connections like listening, speaking, etc.

in commands.py a dictionary, where the value is the command and the key the function that you have to execute, making use of the skills.

in the mediator.py, I'm calling commands functions.

in the main.py I call the mediator.

I'm not using an object because I do not know in what way I can implement the. Any idea or opinion is good, thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too opinion based. Answer for this would be too general and each developer have his own style: how to actually form a project structure, how to name files, etc. You can look e.g. here ( https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/ ) or just type to google **Common python project structure** for some styles.

Comment: For sure you can use a class @jlgf which will also reduce the number of files you need to maintain, take a look at my answer :)

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Very friendly.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks you for your answer friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would suggest taking a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html#distributing-index on how to package your python modules

You can surely use a class which will reduce the number of files you need to maintain and you also have a representation of a virtual assistant.

So your class might look like below. Here I have put my map inside the class but you can have it outside and import and refer to it inside the class as well

```
class VirtualAssistant:

    #Map of commands to skill functions
    COMMAND_MAP = {'1': self.listening_skill,
                   '2': self.speaking_skill}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    #Function to define skills
    def listening_skill(self, params):
        pass

    def speaking_skill(self, params):
        pass

    #Other skills will be here

    #Take a command and params and execute corresponding skill
    def execute_skill(self, command, params):

        skill_to_execute = VirtualAssistant.COMMAND_MAP[command]
        skill_to_execute(params)
```

Here you have everything you want in one class, now you can fill up the function accordingly, or change the structure to suit your case, but this is what I will think will be a skeleton to being with